# Why does Python keep a reference count on False and True?

Tags: python, reference-counting, python-c-api

I was looking at the source code to the hasattr built-in function and noticed a couple of lines that piqued my interest:

```
Py_INCREF(Py_False);
return Py_False;

...

Py_INCREF(Py_True);
return Py_True;
```

Aren't `Py_False` and `Py_True` global values?  Just out of sheer curiosity, why is Python keeping a reference count for these variables?

Comment: -1: How does this solve any programming problem you currently have?

Comment: @S.Lott since when to questions here have to relate to particular concrete programming problems.

Comment: I currently have the problem that I don't understand the need to increment the reference counts on Py_True and Py_False.

Comment: @Triptych: I'm confused as to how a question like "why this?" has relevance to any programming problem.  If someone is maintaining the Python source code, then perhaps this is relevant.  Otherwise, I'm not seeing how this is a helpful, useful or even interesting question.

Comment: I find these types of questions the most interesting.  Too many questions amount to, "How do I make this specific thing work?", and then the OP moves on to some other pressing concern.  This question will actually lead to a deeper understanding of the system as a whole, and therefore better programming within that system.

Comment: @Triptych: It's people like you that inhibit the growth of a programmers knowledge and need to understand, which oft-times lead to new insight.

Comment: @Chazadanga. LOL I think you're confused.

Comment: @Chazadanga, surely that comment was aimed at S.Lott, otherwise it makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's to make all object handling uniform.  If I'm writing C code that handles a return value from a function, I have to increment and decrement the reference count on that object.  If the function returns me True, I don't want to have to check to see if it's one of those special objects to know whether to manipulate its reference count.  I can treat all objects identically.

By treating True and False (and None, btw) the same as all other objects, the C code is much simpler throughout.

Comment: Additionally: T F and None are actually objects. They just don't have any methods. http://docs.python.org/c-api/bool.html

Comment: they technically have methods. Every object has methods.

Comment: len(dir(True)) is 54 -- chock *full* of methods. They're just all special (double-underscores-named) ones.

Comment: Likely Unladen Swallow will change this. This is exactly the kind of things they are trying to optimize.

Comment: @Alex:  I think Pod meant that Py_True and Py_False don't have any methods.  For example, the documentation for Py_False says:  "The Python False object. This object has no methods. It needs to be treated just like any other object with respect to reference counts."

Comment: *"Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."*