# Bus error in Python with C extension

Tags: python, c

Recently i have been working on programming python module with C extension.
( python2.7, gcc 4.1.2)
Once done and testing. i found following bus error.

does anybody know why?

p.s before i got this error. i fixed 'return Py_False related error' described in

[Application gives segmentation fault randomly in python extension functions in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814490/application-gives-segmentation-fault-randomly-in-python-extension-functions-in-c)

Core was generated by `python2.7 app.py --debug=False --multi_slaves=True`

> Program terminated with signal 7, Bus error.
>   #0  0x0000003d22272cf1 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>   (gdb) where
>   #0  0x0000003d22272cf1 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>   #1  0x0000003d22274e4e in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>   #2  0x00000000004d3069 in _PyObject_GC_Malloc (basicsize=`<value optimized out>`) at Modules/gcmodule.c:1445
>   #3  0x000000000046408c in PyType_GenericAlloc (type=0x768360, nitems=0) at Objects/typeobject.c:753
>   #4  0x00000000004477ec in dict_new (type=0x3d225539e0, args=, kwds=0x7fff8dcb4eb0) at Objects/dictobject.c:2301
>   #5  0x00000000004661c3 in type_call (type=0x3d225539e0, args=0x2b3e5a521050, kwds=0x2239bca0) at Objects/typeobject.c:721
>   #6  0x00000000004189cd in PyObject_Call (func=0x768360, arg=0x2b3e5a521050, kw=0x2239bca0) at Objects/abstract.c:2529

c extension code looks like this

```
static PyObject* analyze( PyObject *self, PyObject *args )
{
    int     ret;
    char*   in;

    // global variables : void* obj, char* outbuf, int outbuf_size;
    if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &in)){
        ret = process(obj, in, outbuf, outbuf_size);
        if ( ret == SUCCESS ) {
            PyObject* py_out = PyString_FromString(outbuf);
            return py_out;
        } else {
            Py_INCREF(Py_False);
            return Py_False;
        }
    } else {
        Py_INCREF(Py_False);
        return Py_False;
    }
}
```

~

Comment: That very much looks like your module messes something up. Can you post the [complete source code of a module that exhibits the problem](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: c extension module, first initialize void* obj, and then call analyze(obj, in, ...). problem appears here.

Comment: Although the problem appears in `analyze`, the actual error is most likely somewhere completely different (say, a double `free`). Can you post *complete* code that still exhibits the problem? Also, the example code is obviously invalid - `outbuf` is never declared.

Comment: I would think the usual thing to do would be to compile with `--debug=True` and run your code through a debugger; that should at least give you the exact point where things crash.

Comment: @phihag outbuf is global variable. and process() is very long c code. so it's not proper to post here. sorry ^^;;

Comment: @phihag before developing python module, c code was tested. there was no problem.

Comment: I recommend you run your unit tests on `process()`, preferably in conjunction with some code tool like Valgrind.

Comment: Build Python with Asan and UBsan enabled and fix the findings. It is usually due to a misaligned double on x86. In your case it may be a wild write elsewhere. Also see [Dynamic Analysis with Clang](https://devguide.python.org/clang/) in the Python manual.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I was getting a Bus error from a python program. Turned out to be related to it allocating shared memory. I was running it in a docker container and had to set `docker run ... --shm_size=1g` as described in:
https://goblincoding.com/2018/02/19/docker-bus-error-no-space-left-on-device/